# Protocol buffers in gRPC cannot save large float numbers - what to do?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using protocol buffers with gRPC. I have my .proto file look like

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option objc_class_prefix = "DRPC";

package my_rpc;

service RPCData {
  // Sends a cycle of data
  rpc RunRequest (CycleData) returns (OutputScores) {}
}

message CycleData {
  repeated float timestamps = 1;
  repeated float values = 2;
}
```

But the system seems to cut of my values:

```
>>> dtw_rpc_pb2.CycleData(timestamps=[1501545616.742662], values=[5])
timestamps: 1501545600.0
values: 5.0
```

I guess it is not able to represent those large values accurately:

```
>>> dtw_rpc_pb2.CycleData(timestamps=[16.742662], values=[5])
timestamps: 16.74266242980957
values: 5.0
>>> dtw_rpc_pb2.CycleData(timestamps=[45616.742662], values=[5])
timestamps: 45616.7421875
values: 5.0
>>> dtw_rpc_pb2.CycleData(timestamps=[1545616.742662], values=[5])
timestamps: 1545616.75
values: 5.0
>>> dtw_rpc_pb2.CycleData(timestamps=[1501545616.742662], values=[5])
timestamps: 1501545600.0
values: 5.0
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar) is a little misleading (it implies that the cast to Python-float is independent from the proto type, so I thought it would not help), but if one uses "double" it works.

So, I needed to change

```
message CycleData {
  repeated float timestamps = 1;
  repeated float values = 2;
}
```

to

```
message CycleData {
  repeated double timestamps = 1;
  repeated float values = 2;
}
```

The background is, as Jie Luo explains in the comments, that Python's float actually already has double precision. There is no C-style float. Protobuf on the other hand does recognize "float" and "double" as different types. Using Protobuf's double type is actually the same as Python's float, while Protobuf's float would decrease the precision, resulting in the issues described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

For pure python protobuf, python-float is used for float and double. But the cpp implementation calls some C++ protobuf code, makes it different with pure python.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Can you elaborate? Is a python float encoded with more bytes than a C++ float? (I thought both are encoded with 32 bytes?) What is "cpp"? Is it the C++ compiler?

Comment: Python does not have C-style float, it only has a C-style double. Python's built-in float type has double precision.   
Yes by "cpp" I mean c++.  "--cpp_implementation" is a flag we used for python protobuf if someone want to use the c++ implementation: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/python/README.md

I believe gRPC is using the cpp_implementation

Comment: @Make42 gRPC Python pip package, lists the protobuf pip package as a dependency. Depending on the platform on which you pip install, the Python protobuf package loads up one of the two underlying code paths, one using a Python extension written in C++, and the other written in Python natively). gRPC itself uses whichever underlying protobuf installation and is happy with either, but there might be minor behavior differences as you encountered. There is a PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python environment variable that forces pure python code path even when C++ extension is available.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari: That clarified a lot, thanks! Do you know what the differences are and where to find more information on the subject? (I guess the C++ implementation is faster.)

Comment: @Make42 I'm not sure if the differences are fully documented, since the goal is for them to behave identically except for speed. If you find a difference in supported behavior, it should be considered a bug and an issue should be filed for it. This particular one may not particularly be easy to fix though without some trade-offs, I'd imagine.